# Uploading an Image to Instagram with Instagram API

Tags: c#, android, ios, instagram

I have been searching the internet that "how to upload an image to instagram with instagram api" and found many replies. Most of the people are saying that it is not possible and they are referring to [this link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/). Since all of these replies are old and I could not find the text

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>   Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
>   We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

This makes me to post this question again. Does anybody have any idea? I think it can be done with android and IOS apps!

I want to upload am image with a link and some caption through the web using C#. Please guide me if it is possible, any help tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: you got any answere from somewhere? Please share

Answer (score 0):

Analyse and learn how to use this library and methods described there. You can even write your own library in C# if you understand the approach he is using there.

https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API