# How can I post my website link Instagram like on facebook that it fetch site logo and page title?

Tags: instagram

I am dealing with an image (shown below).

How can I post the same on Instagram?

For Facebook I am using the following meta tag info:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="4 Ways to Strengthen Weak Body Parts" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.labrada.com/articles/wp-content/themes/article/images/labradalogo.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="450" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="397" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.labrada.com/articles/" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="It can be a bit degrading when everything except for a few muscles grow consistently and imbalances if your overall shape start to become apparent. One of the most frustrating things is when you put y" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Labrada" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no method of sharing a website link on instagram, apart from placing it on your profile in the 'Website' section. Any link placed there is simply displayed as a plain url, and hence no meta tags can change it's appearance.

Regardless of this, you cannot interact with instagram's API through basic web technologies alone so there is no way to easily implement a method for visitors to share your website. They currently do not support sharing external content (specifically images, but these are required in every instagram post):

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
> 2. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into
>      the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>      ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>      platform.

Despite this there are a few workarounds available for sharing content from a website, but these would require much more effort than just meta tags:

- [C# Instagram API Interaction from web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40306502/8310261)
- [Alternative methods for sharing to Instagram through API from web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844791/8310261)

**So in short, there are currently no OpenGraph (og) or alternative meta tags that will affect how a web link appears when shared through instagram.**